# Get the center of chordal graph by deleting all simplicial vertices at each step.

Tags: graph-theory

As a example,we can get the center of tree by deleting all leaves at each step.Then we can finally get one or two vertices that is center of tree.

We haver known that the tree is chordal graph,and its leaves are simplicail vertices. So I wonder whether we can get the center of chordal graph by deleting all simplicial vertices at each step or not?

Answer (score 1):

This certainly won't work if you delete *all* simplicial vertices at each step. 
Consider the example graph below. All the vertices of the $K_4$ subgraph, including the red one, are in the center of the graph.
However, the red vertex is also simplicial, so if you delete all simplicial vertices in the first step, you end up losing some of the center.

[image: example]